# Getting data-attributes from slides in slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

After the 1.4 update to Slick carousel, the method to pull data attributes from the current slide changed.

The previous method which worked:

```
onAfterChange: function(slide, index) {
   $('.project-caption').find('p').replaceWith("<p>" + $(slide.$slides.get(index)).data('description') + "</p>");
}
```

Now the documentation says to call current slide after change like this:

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    console.log(nextSlide);
});`
```

I've tried everything I know to get the data attribute using the new method.

Author show me how to get the current Slide as an integer here: http://jsfiddle.net/3b4kqy9p/

But does anyone know how to get the current slide data-attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the `$slides` array from the slick object:

```
var elSlide = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]);
var materials = elSlide.data('materials');
```

I have updated the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arcadeGandalf/3b4kqy9p/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your event handler put:

```
var activeSlide = $('#carousel').find('.slick-active');
var year = activeSlide.data('year');
```

this works based on the class changing made by the plugin.